# Do we have or can have in future FTP solutions and text editors on windows phone 8

Tags: 8.0, ftp

I am upgrading from Nokia lumia 710 running windows 7.8 to other platform. FTP solutions and text/code editors are primary requirement. As of now, I am thinking to switch to iPhone 4 as it's in my budget and has FTP solution as well as text/code editor.

But, my preferred choice is windows platform only. Are there such applications available on windows phone 8 platform. In case not, can these applications be developed in future? Or the Microsoft OS is still too restrictive for such applications.

Comment: Probably with text editor you mean something like Notepad, not Word, right?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** both types are applications are possible and exist in the store.

In future, if you want to know if a certain app or type of app exists on Windows Phone, simply visit the official website and search. Lots of FTP sites exist...

- [Windows Phone Store - FTP apps](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/search?q=ftp)

As for a decent code editor, I could only find apps that are...

- Part of what you need: [Code Reader](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/code-reader/33694fad-8a1d-470c-9ad2-8aec2f7c461b)
- A little rough around the edges: [HTML_Pro](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/html_pro/82408a50-be43-4b79-9c73-5f88159e1392) or [Easy Compiler ++](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/easy-compiler/45b20067-cd1b-45c7-ab19-54b268e1c4ff)

Both from these examples and as a developer of apps on the platform, code editors and FTP apps are technically possible, and like many things, will improve over time.

Comment: I suspect that OP wants a solution that can edit the files hosted on the FTP server. As apps can only access their own files on Windows Phone, you would need an FTP app that handles text editing internally.

Comment: @NikRolls you're right, I've updated the answer with what I've found so far.